# determine dynamically which static method to invoke

Tags: c#, static, introspection

In my domain model, I have a base entity class from which all classes derive.
I'd like to be able to create filters dynamically based on current user's permissions.
For example- For the Employee class, I would define that an employee can see himself, and his department.
My method would go something like this:

```
 public static IQueryable<Employee> CreateLinqFilter(IQueryable<Employee> query, User user)
    {
        return query.Where(e => e.Id == user.Id || e.Department.Manager.Id == user.Id);
    }
```

and then, in my repository base class, I'd like to determine the type dynamically and call the correct CreateLinqFilter method:

```
protected IQueryable CreateLinq<T>(User user)
    {
        var query = Session.Linq<T>();
        Type t = typeof(T);
        //if not an entity- do not perform filter
        if (!t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Entity)))
        {
            return query;
        }
        //now we know that T is a sub-class of Entity. 
        return CreateLinqFilter<T>(query,user);
    }

protected IQueryable CreateLinqFilter<T>(IQueryable<T> query, User user)
        //the following line won't compile:
        //where T: Entity
    {
        //i'd like to be able to do:
        //T.CreateFilter(query);

        //instead, I have to do this?
        if (typeof(T) == Employee)
        {
            return Employee.CreateLinqFilter(query,user);
        }
        if (typeof(T) == Department)
        {
            return Department.CreateLinqFilter(query,user);
        }
        //etc...
    }
```

The only solution I've got so far is lots of if-else blocks, which are quite unsightly.
anyone got a better idea?
thanks
Jhonny

Comment: I'm almost certainly missing something here but why don't you just declare a "CreateLinqFilter" on your Entity class and then instead of all this relfection type stuff or just if statements couldn't you just call "entity.CreateLinqFilter and it will just call it on the right thing? As I say, I'm probably missing something and I'd like to knwo what. ;-)

Comment: @Chris since the CreateLinqFilter function works on *Collections* of entities, it's pretty meaningless in a context of a single entity; the function is actually static...

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. I still occasionally have trouble getting my head around generics and where they need to live. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
return (IQueryable)typeof(T).GetMethod("CreateLinqFilter").Invoke(null, new object[]{query, user});
```

This uses reflection to find the method at runtime; if this is too slow you may want to consider caching the result of `GetMethod` somewhere. Note that this method is not restricted to static method; replace the null with a pointer to an object of type T and you can use it on normal instance methods as well.

For more information, consult the [MSDN documentation for the reflection classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/136wx94f.aspx); you can find a nice example in the [documentation for Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx).

Comment: well, nobody likes reflection, but it does work, and at the moment it seems to be the best answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in c#4.0, you can use  dynamic a=T t, if not, maybe you can only use first answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, don't use a lot of if..else blocks, use a switch.

Answer (score 0):

The really good solution, IMO is simply calling the method in the derived repository class and not in your base repository. Then you have no problem because the derived class knows what it is querying, so EmployeesRepository will explicitly call Employee.GetFilter.